# Data labels hide in high charts when using sharing plugin in cordova ios

Tags: ios, cordova

our data labels initially are shown in high charts but are getting hide after we are using sharing plugin.we are using cordova for ios platform.

please provide solution to the problem.
we are attaching screenshot of before using plugin and after using plugin what changes are occurring[before using sharing plugin[[image: after using sharing plugin[![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SedGs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZkxD.png).

Comment: I think you uploaded the same image for twice. Check and upload the before using sharing plugin image.